# Write buffer to file with child process

Tags: node.js, buffer, fs

I was wondering, is it possible instead of `fs.writeFileSync(path, buffer)` in order to write a buffer to disk, to spawn a child process to do it?

The whole idea is to do it in some way faster than `writeFileSync`.

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking the input in the path before using `writeFileSync` or you can use document API as an alternative. `writeFileSync` is a very optimised method which is pretty fast. Your question looks more logical the technical.